# Do long blasts of the horn damage it?

Tags: damage, wear, horn

I have recently had to blast my horn for about 2 minutes while I was driving.

Got me wondering: **Does using the horn for long periods of time damage it/wear it out?**

2003 Opel Agila

Comment: Only if you use it too long, then someone might shoot you.

Comment: In what kind of situation you HAVE to blast the horn for two minutes?

Comment: I think I have road rage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No not at all, the horn is not gonna get damaged. My old Nissan Maxima once had a faulty hood lock switch and the alarm went off during night. The alarm was on for almost all the night and the horn was honking too, I knew it the next day when there was a notice hanging on my apartment door.